# How do I get map specific events (like Mortar or KEM Strike) in COD: Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

Several times I'll be playing multiplayer in COD Ghosts and the opposing team will call in some kind of killstreak (like KEM Strike) that kills the entire team and changes the map layout.

How do I get these and which maps have them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On specific maps (Whiteout, Warhawk, Strikezone, Sovereign, Bayview, Ignition, Containment), there is a chance to get one of these events from care packages, which you get by completing field orders.  I've had them appear on my first care crate, my third and sometimes not at all.

On Sovereign you get the Halon Gas, on Warhawk the Mortar Strike, on Strikezone you get the K.E.M and on Whiteout you get the Satellite Crash, on Bayview you get something like the Morter Strike, on Ignition you get a count down for as launch that gets blown up,  on Containment you get a Air strike that blows up the Nuke crate in the middle of the map. The Mortar and KEM strikes and the most dangerous (especially on hardcore) and the KEM and Satellite strikes affect the map layout.

Comment: thanks, i got the Mortar Strike kill streak the other day from a field order care package.  this seems legit.

Comment: You can also get for 25 kills per map or 24 with hardline

Answer (score 0):

The K.E.M. Strike is a 25 kill "kill streak" that occurs when a player racks up 25 kills and has the killstreak selected before hand/unlocked.  It can be deactivated with a ground jammer.

More info can be found here: http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/K.E.M._Strike

Comment: This is painfully incorrect. You can only get the K.E.M strike on Strike zone and only by completing field orders. There is absolutely no way to counter or defend against it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the K.E.M. Strike on any map as long as get 25 kills without dying (24) with hard line.